# Twitter Bootstrap Menu styling on Mobiles

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap and my menu currently display like:
[image: menu]
which is perfect but i need to when in mobile view have the menu display like:
[image]

Now I know I need to use media query's and such that's not the problem, the problem is how in CSS do i get my menu styled like that with the lines and such...?

Here's is the HTML:

```
<!--SUBMENU-->
<div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span12 submenu">
       <ul class="nav menu nav-pills">
            <li class="item-109"><a href="/stradix/index.php/company-profile" >Company Profile</a></li>
            <li class="item-108"><a href="/stradix/index.php/due-diligence" >Due Diligence</a></li>
            <li class="item-110"><a href="/stradix/index.php/our-solution" >Our Solution</a></li>
            <li class="item-111"><a href="/stradix/index.php/loan-process" >Loan Process</a></li>
            <li class="item-112"><a href="/stradix/index.php/currency-converter" >Currency Converter</a></li>
            <li class="item-113"><a href="/stradix/index.php/loan-calculator" >Loan Calculator</a></li>
            <li class="item-114"><a href="/stradix/index.php/news" >News</a></li>
            <li class="item-115"><a href="/stradix/index.php/important-downloads" >Downloads</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<!--SUBMENU-->
```

and The CSS to override default bootstrap:

```
.submenu .nav-pills > li > a {
    font-size:1.25em; 
    padding:0; 
    margin:2em 0.9em 0 0;
    padding: 0 0.9em 0 0;
    color:#6D6E70; 
    border-right:1px solid #A7A9AB;
    border-radius:0;
}
.submenu .nav-pills a:hover {
    background:none;
    color:#00ADEE;
}
.submenu .nav-pills > .active > a {
    background:none;
    color:#00ADEE;
}

.submenu .nav-pills > li:last-child > a {
        border-right:none;
        padding: 0;
        margin-right:0;
}
```

I Would post it on JSFIDDLE But for some reason I am still since Friday unable to connect to jsfiddle..

Any Help Greatly appreciated.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this to achieve the desired effect

```
@media (max-width: 480px) { 

 .nav-pills > li {
float: left;
width: 50%;
 }
}
```

Check out  [my JSFiddle for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/jeNmY/)